# Install bootstrap through composer, how to use it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php

I am using Laravel 5.1. I want to add bootstrap to my project using composer.

How would i refer to it in my files? Basically how do i add it to my project?

Do i have to manually add the min files somewhere. Currently i am using a CDN.

Comment: You may want to consider using a front end package manager rather than composer for things like Bootstrap. Composer was intended to be used for php package management.

Comment: @Jeemusu I tried using npm, but the same question applies to that as well. Also, the directory becomes too big if i continue to use it for other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it myself, but I've looked at, and would recommend using Component to do this. So first you need to get the [Component installer](https://packagist.org/packages/robloach/component-installer) Composer package. That should do the job of actually copying your component dependencies to somewhere sensible.

Now you can `composer require component/bootstrap` and that will install Bootstrap (and its dependencies) by composer. Upon installation, the Component installer should copy the assets to where you need them.

By default this is `/components/` which is no good for Laravel, so make sure you add the following (or similar) into your `composer.json` file:

```
"config": {
    "component-dir": "public/assets",
    "component-baseurl": "/assets"
}
```

---

See the [Component installer's documentation](http://robloach.github.io/component-installer/) for full details.